# Remove Titles (Name, Size, etc.) from Directory Listing htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, directory-listing

I am using htaccess to list the files in a directory.
Currently, I am using only names. 
I do not know how to remove "Name" title from the page.
I searched but didn't find a reference on this.

[image: Capture]

I can remove it when I use HTMLTable, but then I am not able to use multicolumns in firefox, because firefox does not support multi column in table elements.

Option 1: Without using HTMLTable, finding a way to remove the "Name" Title.

Option 2: Using HTMLTable, find a way to show the created table in multi-column in firefox.

Option 3: Finding a way to use HTMLTable for all browsers except Firefox, and do not use HTMLTable for Firefox.

Thanks.